# Invoking a C function dynamically at runtime without knowing its prototype

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, ld

I want to know if it is possible to achieve above. Apparently it is possible to load a library and invoke method of it using `dlopen, dlsym` methods in Linux. But it requires knowing the function prototype to cast the `void *` pointer to the respective type before invocation.

Assuming prototype metadata can be provided externally (using some descriptor file etc.)

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: This is not possible in general, I believe (though maybe some hack using varargs might work). Do you have a specific purpose in mind?

Comment: C is not a Dynamic language like python or javascritp, you must know the prototype of your function

Comment: @larsmans In fact this is for some experimental code that I am trying to write for a RPC server like functionality where the parameters you get via a HTTP call would be used to invoke some function present in a library which can be loaded at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible for sure, but don't expect anything portable. For example, you may be able to use the infamous [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) library. Dummy example in pseudo-C:

```
// We make some kind of descriptor structure and possible return and argument types
enum c_type {
    C_TYPE_CHAR,
    C_TYPE_INT,
    C_TYPE_FLOAT,
    C_TYPE_PTR,
    C_TYPE_VOID
};

struct func_proto_desc {
    enum c_type ret_type;
    int n_args; // Reasonable convention: -1 for variadic
    c_type *arg_types;
};

// Imaginary function that parses textual metadata and returns a function descriptor
void parse_func_desc(const char *str, struct func_proto_desc *desc);

// this is how to use it:
struct func_proto_desc fproto;
parse_func_desc("void (*)(int, float, const char *)", &fproto);

ffi_cif cif;
ffi_type *args[3];
void *vals[3];

int n = 42;
float f = 3.1415927;
const char *s = "Hello world!";

vals[0] = &n;
vals[1] = &f;
vals[2] = &s;

// Here you can set up the types according to the type description
// that the parser function returned
// (this one is an imaginary function too)
populate_ffi_types_from_desc(args, &fproto);

// Use libffi to call the function
ffi_prep_cif(&cif, FFI_DEFAULT_ABI, fproto->n_args, &ffi_type_void, args);
ffi_call(&cif, func_ptr, NULL, vals);
```

Something like this should get you started.

Comment: This seems feasible. Accepting this as the correct answer since I don't see any stumbling blocks with this approach. Will try this out and see. But just curious how this library achieves some thing which is not supported by the language it self.

Comment: @chamibuddhika It uses heavy and evil assembly hacking :)